# How to Override 'border:none' to Overcome Safari Select Bug?

Tags: javascript, css, safari

We've just discovered a pretty random bug in Safari (at least on Mac). It seems that Safari doesn't like a border style applied to a `<select>` tag. It will do different things depending on the version of Safari, from kind of working to no drop-down to refreshing the page.

But we've applied `border: none;` to our select fields to match our styling better. It appears to work OK in other browsers though (including Chrome).

So I need to know how to 'override' this style just for Safari. We created a style sheet just for Safari, but I don't think this is going to help since there is no `border: auto;` value. Tried `border: inherit`, but this didn't work either.

Options? Ideas? THANKS!

Comment: Here's a thought: How 'bout an *example* of the problem? ;-) Code/markup is worth a thousand words...

Comment: You can use border: none on a `<select>` in Safari: http://particletree.com/examples/safari3/drop.html (checked this with Safari 5.1). As @T.J.Crowder said, provide a example.

Comment: @Kenny Setting the `border` property results in refreshing the page? I don't believe that.

Comment: OK, site in dev, so be discrete, but here's a link: https://50.22.77.42/take-action/donate (security alerts due to site not being live yet).

And Safari 4.0.4 on Mac 10.5.8 has no drop-downs.
Safari 5.1 on 10.7.x causes page to refresh.
Safari 5.1 on WinXP is OK.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165086/clicking-safari-5-1-select-menu-refreshes-page.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the little yellow/blue border around text boxes and other inputs, you need to add the property outline:none; to your style.

Answer (score 0):

I know that Safari doesn't like you to style their select tags even if you add it in as !important. I'm still looking for ways around this. I have custom made select tags made out of div tags, but the sizing is a bit screwed up on Safari because it won't allow me to overwrite it's padding. You can see this if you inspect element, click on "Computed Styles", & check "Show Inherited".

Answer (score 0):

This post is a bit old but in case it would help anyone, here is my solution even if it's not the best way to do this, but at least it worked for me.

I had an issue where the width of my div tag was defined at "600px" by Safari (I never chose this size anywhere), so I added the style directly to my html tag :

```
<div id="container" style="width: auto"></div>
```