# Page refreshes when you click on any SELECT box in a SAFARI browser

Tags: html, css, safari

The page refreshes as soon as you click on any `SELECT` box. This happens only in **SAFARI** browser. I have also tested the same in **CHROME** and **FIREFOX** and it works great!!

**ISSUE ON > SAFARI VERSION (Safari 12.1 on macOS Mojave)**

I have found a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165086/clicking-safari-5-1-select-menu-refreshes-page%E3%80%82) but there is no specific solution for this issue.

Has anyone ever faced this issue? If yes, please share if you found any solution.

> ### UPDATED

When I remove the font-family from the `SELECT` box `CSS` it does not reload the page.

But is there any solution where I can apply the same font style without reloading the page?

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:400,500,600,700&display=swap');

body {
  font-family: Quicksand, sans-serif;
}

.select-box {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}

select {
  font-family: Quicksand, sans-serif;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.select-box .chevron {
  position: absolute;
  top: 14px;
  right: 12px;
  height: 8px;
  width: 8px;
  border-right: 1px solid #666;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="select-box">
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<span class="chevron"></span>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clicking Safari 5.1 select menu refreshes page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165086/clicking-safari-5-1-select-menu-refreshes-page)

Comment: Hi, @PrabhjotSinghKainth  Yes, this is a possible duplicate of the question but I didn't find a solution for the same.

Answer (score 1):

Creating your own font-kit can resolve this. You have to set specific `font-family` by making font-face for the `select` tag and add `font-family` from the font-face.

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'quicksandregular';
    src: url('quicksand-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('quicksand-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

select{
    font-family: 'quicksandregular';
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have added local `@font-face` and applied that `css` to `select` and it worked.